# Virtual deconstructors in interface->abstract->concrete class design

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have tried to answer this myself, by looking up several questions at StackOverflow. And although I think I understand this correctly, I can't fix this. Which, leaves me with the only obvious observation: I still don't get it.

I have made a summary of the questions at the bottom of this post, everything in between is information I have gathered and context for this question.

So, I get it that when you have a base class, and a derived class, your deconstructor should be marked virtual in the base class. To allow polymorphism.

But, I cannot seem to get my code to compile, or when it does compile, it does not link due 'undefined references'. I have been changing back and forth, but I never seem to get out of this cycle.

Basically I have an interace, defined like this:

```
#ifndef GUIELEMENT_H_
#define GUIELEMENT_H_

class GuiElement {
    public:
    virtual ~GuiElement();
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

#endif /* GUIELEMENT_H_ */
```

I have several objects extending from this. A simple relation is GuiWindow (directly derives from GuiElement):

```
#ifndef CGUIWINDOW_H_
#define CGUIWINDOW_H_

#include <assert.h>
#include <cstddef>

#include "../GuiElement.h"
#include "../GuiInteractionDelegate.h"

class GuiWindow : public GuiElement {

    public:
        GuiWindow(GuiInteractionDelegate * guiInteractionDelegate) {
            assert(guiInteractionDelegate);
            interactionDelegate = guiInteractionDelegate;
        }

        ~GuiWindow() {
            //delete interactionDelegate;
        }

        // called each frame, delegates its behavior to the given concrete cGuiWindowDelegate class.
        void interact() {
            interactionDelegate->interact(this);
        }

    private:
        GuiInteractionDelegate * interactionDelegate;

};

#endif /* CGUIWINDOW_H_ */
```

This code does not link, gives me:

> undefined reference to `GuiElement::~GuiElement()'

I thought it was sufficient to have an implementation in the GuiWindow class? Is that correct?

The next thing, which is really bugging me, is that I also have an abstract class derived from GuiElement, and concrete implementations on top of that. Basically giving:
GuiElement->GuiShape->GuiButton

Here is the header of GuiShape:

```
#ifndef GUISHAPE_H_
#define GUISHAPE_H_

#include "../GuiElement.h"
#include "../../gameobjects/Rectangle.h"

class GuiShape : public GuiElement {

    public:
        GuiShape(Rectangle * rect);
        GuiShape(int x, int y, int width, int height);

        ~GuiShape();

        void draw();

        void setX(int value) { rectangle->setStartX(value);     }
        void setY(int value) { rectangle->setStartY(value);     }

        Rectangle * getRectangle() { return rectangle; }

        bool isMouseOverShape();

        void setColors(int darkBorder, int lightBorder, int inner);

        int getDarkBorderColor() { return darkBorderColor; }
        int getLightBorderColor() { return lightBorderColor; }
        int getInnerColor() { return innerColor; }

    protected:
        Rectangle * rectangle;

    private:
        bool rectangleOwner;
        int darkBorderColor;
        int lightBorderColor;
        int innerColor;
};
```

And finally GuiButton:

```
#ifndef CGUIBUTTON_H_
#define CGUIBUTTON_H_

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "allegro.h"

#include "../../gameobjects/Rectangle.h"
#include "GuiShape.h"

class GuiButton : public GuiShape {

    public:
        GuiButton(Rectangle * rect, std::string theLabel);
        GuiButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string theLabel);
        ~GuiButton();

        void draw();

        std::string * getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        BITMAP * getBitmap() { return bitmap; }
        void setBitmap(BITMAP * value) { bitmap = value; }
        void setHasBorders(bool value) { hasBorders = value; }
        void setPressed(bool value) { pressed = value; }

        bool shouldDrawPressedWhenMouseHovers() { return drawPressedWhenMouseHovers; }
        bool shouldDrawBorders() { return hasBorders; }
        void setDrawPressedWhenMouseHovers(bool value) { drawPressedWhenMouseHovers = value; }
        bool isPressed() { return pressed; }

    private:
        std::string * label;
        bool drawPressedWhenMouseHovers;
        bool hasBorders;
        bool pressed;
        BITMAP * bitmap;

        void drawBackground();
        void drawLighterBorder();
        void drawDarkerBorder();
        void drawButtonUnpressed();
        void drawButtonPressed();
};

#endif /* CGUIBUTTON_H_ */
```

Which leads me to the following questions:

- What is the best way to use virtual deconstructors where objects are derived from A->B->C ?
- Should C only be the concrete virtual? And if so, how do you release resources defined and handled only in B? (A=GuiElement, B=GuiShape, C=GuiButton)
- Why would I get 'undefined references' with the straight-forward implementation of A->B ? (GuiElement->GuiWindow)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: After you get your answer here do this : put debug outputs to all your descrutctors/constructors and observe the order they are getting called when you created/delete objects. You will then understand what is going on.

Comment: Although i think i know the answer i will try it :)

Comment: I'm trying the answers out on my code, but I end up with 'multiple implementations' of the deconstructor (although it is virtual, and I also give it an implementation). Any hints on that? In the meantime I keep on trying.

Comment: I got it working. What i did:
- i made all destructors, except the most concrete classes virtual.
- I created implementations of the destructors, so they could release resources, etc. 
- I also made sure that all virtual functions on the interface class, where also mentioned virtual in the base class (B in A->B->C).

Comment: I did put debug outputs in the destructor, here is what i got. Actually quite the opposite I was thinking...:
[DEBUG] - destructor GuiElement
[DEBUG] - destructor GuiMainMenuWindow
[DEBUG] - destructor GuiMainMenuWindowInteractionDelegate
[DEBUG] - destructor GuiWindow
[DEBUG] - destructor GuiElement
[DEBUG] - destructor State

Comment: You should also do the same for constructors - you will see that the order of destruction is the reversed order of construction, which makes sense of course :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to use virtual deconstructors where objects are derived from A->B->C ?

mark the base's (or all) destructor as virtual.

> Should C only be the concrete virtual? And if so, how do you release resources defined and handled only in B? (A=GuiElement, B=GuiShape, C=GuiButton)

Not sure what you mean by "concrete virtual" but a class with members that need destroying should destroy them in it's own destructor.  No exceptions.  when `~C` is called, it destroys it's *own* stuff, and then `~B` will be called *automatically*.  The virtual just makes absolutely sure that `~C` is called first.

> Why would I get 'undefined references' with the straight-forward implementation of A->B ? (GuiElement->GuiWindow)

`virtual ~GuiElement();` tells the compiler that the class has a destructor that will be defined later.  You wanted either:

```
// There is no definition, cannot make a local "GuiElement" variable
// They can only make local "GuiButton" or other derived.
// You can still have pointers to a GuiElement.
// This is called "pure virtual"
virtual ~GuiElement() = 0;
```

or:

```
// There is a definition, someone can make a local "GuiElement" variable
virtual ~GuiElement()  {};
```

Comment: it's destructor, not desconstructor. Also, virtual ~GuiElement()  {}; has a definition, it's the {}

Comment: yeah, I always end up typing "deconstructor" :(  And the second was a copy-paste bug.

Comment: With "concrete virtual" i meant having the virtual defined in the class and then have an implementation of it. I'll try out tonight to see if i get it working, thx for your answer

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it was sufficient to have an implementation in the GuiWindow class? Is that correct?

No. A virtual function (that is not pure virtual, as your destructor of GuiElement) must be defined if it is declared in the class.

Destructors go even further: they must be implemented, always, even if it is pure virtual[1]. If you hadn't declared it, the compiler would create one (implicitly nonvirtual, but would be virtual if it would override a virtual destructor) for you. In C++11, you can just mark it "defaulted" (which means "compiler, implement that for me") and "deleted" which means "the program may never, implicitly or explicitly, destruct objects of this type".

> 1. What is the best way to use virtual deconstructors where objects are derived from A->B-
>      C ?

You usually want to make the topmost base's destructor virtual, that means all destructors in the hierarchy are virtual.

> And if so, how do you release resources defined and handled only in B? (A=GuiElement, B=GuiShape, C=GuiButton)

In `~B()`, naturally.

[1] :

> 12.4/7: A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any
>   derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined. If a class has a base class with a
>   virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly- declared) is virtual.

Comment: @MooingDuck What jpalecek has said is correct. (Except I don't think that 'you can mark it "defaulted"' is an accurate description for what I would call 'using a defaulted implementation' for a destructor declared `virtual ~T() = 0;`).

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's not true. Even a pure virtual destructor needs to be defined, compare http://ideone.com/SG1U2 and http://ideone.com/jhV2H

Comment: § 12.4/8 `A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined.`  I stand corrected, destructors are an exception.

Comment: @LucDanton: That was probably a little misleading expression. By "you can make it defaulted", I meant http://ideone.com/ebq2m .

Comment: @jpalecek Right. That uses the default implementation, but when it comes to language rules the destructor isn't counted as defaulted, it's user defined (IIRC). This affects things like triviality.

Comment: BTW the OP's destructor is not pure virtual, so the discussion is purely academic.

Comment: @LucDanton: A virtual destructor can never be trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @jpalecek Nope (poor example on my part here). No idea what difference an actual virtual, defaulted destructor (`virtual ~T() = default;`) makes.

Comment: @LucDanton: In n3242 (12.4/4), I read a destructor is trivial if it (among others) isn't virtual. I even get a compile error: http://ideone.com/vMcRc